# ActiveMQ Artemis messages keep stucking in some queue

Tags: java, activemq-artemis

We're using ActiveMQ Artemis 2.17.0. Sometimes the consumers for one specific queue fail and don't consume messages. Other queues are keep working fine. The consumer count on the queue is 0 when this happens. Consumers are using this URL:

```
(tcp://artemis01:61616,tcp://artemis02:61616,tcp://artemis03:61616)?ha=true&sslEnabled=true&trustStorePath=/client.p12&trustStorePassword=123456
```

After restarting servers where consumers are running and sometimes restarting Artemis helps to consume stuck messages from the queue.

I'm not sure what the exact problem is. In Artemis logs I can't see any errors, but in the Java consumer application I found this:

```
thread.name":"Thread-9 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads)","log.logger":"org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client"}
{"@timestamp":"2021-08-18T06:58:48.550Z", "log.level": "WARN", "message":"Caught exception trying close() when putting session back into the pool, will invalidate. javax.jms.IllegalStateExc
eption: Session is closed", "ecs.version": "1.2.0","service.name":"credit-notification","event.dataset":"credit-notification.log","process.thread.name":"Camel (camel-1) thread #1 - JmsConsu
mer[notification]","log.logger":"org.messaginghub.pooled.jms.JmsPoolSession","label_fish_tag":"y6I6BduxnA","label_ref_id":"118089714","error.type":"javax.jms.IllegalStateExcepti
on","error.message":"Session is closed","error.stack_trace":[
        "javax.jms.IllegalStateException: Session is closed",
        "at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQSession.checkClosed(ActiveMQSession.java:1279)",
        "at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQSession.setMessageListener(ActiveMQSession.java:356)",
        "at org.messaginghub.pooled.jms.JmsPoolSession.close(JmsPoolSession.java:91)",
        "at org.springframework.jms.connection.JmsResourceHolder.closeAll(JmsResourceHolder.java:286)",
        "at org.springframework.jms.connection.JmsTransactionManager.doCleanupAfterCompletion(JmsTransactionManager.java:318)",
        "at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.cleanupAfterCompletion(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:1004)",
        "at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:790)",
        "at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:711)",
        "at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:251)",
        "at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1237)",
        "at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1227)",
        "at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1120)",
        "at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)",
        "at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)",
        "at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)"]}
```

Artemis during this time had not any failover.

Comment: Artemis version is 2.17.0. I saw that 2.18.0 is already available, will try to upgrade not sure if it helps

Comment: consumer count is 0 when messages are "stuck", delivering count I didnt noticed probably 0 I assume (the coulmn was hidden)

Comment: yes client will reconnect if failure happened ```jms.artemis.broker.url=(tcp://artemis01:61616,tcp://artemis02:61616,tcp://artemis03:61616)?ha=true&sslEnabled=true&trustStorePath=/client.p12&trustStorePassword=123456```

Comment: @JustinBertram I'm also confused I'm going through documentation of artemis-2.18.0 version and I created "test-broker" of artemis-2.18.0 and I realized that default values what are recommended in documentation are not corresponding to the default values which I see in /test-broker/etc/broker.xml. So what default values should I use then ?

Comment: that's why as soon I restart consumer server, consumer starts read messages from the queue

Comment: What "default values" are you talking about specifically? Also, what exactly do you mean by "consumer server"? Is that the server where the consumers are running or the server where the consumers are consuming messages from?

Comment: default value for example "jorunal-buffer-timeout", "page-sync-timeout" and other properties from broker.xml file. The server where the consumers are running

Comment: I don't understand what those settings have to do with this issue. Can you clarify?

Comment: If your consumer were configured to reconnect in the case of such errors then you wouldn't have to restart the server where they are running in order to restart message consumption.

Comment: should I modify the connection url or how to do that reconnect will occur ? the default values for artemis settings was just another question

Comment: You could try setting `reconnectAttempts` (e.g. `reconnectAttempts=10`) on the URL. Aside from that you could catch the exception in your application and reconnect yourself. That's probably going to be impossible, though, since you're using a connection pool (which wraps the connection and apparently intercepts the exception) as well as Spring (which further removes control of the connection from your application). Ultimately you need to determine why the session is being closed in the first place.

Comment: ok thanks, I will try first 2.18.0 version and then what your suggested. Regarding confusion with default settings for broker.xml should I open another topic ?

Comment: Certainly if you have another, different question then open a new one.

Comment: Did you ever get this sorted out?

Comment: Nope, It happened couple times. After restarting Artemis brokers or sometimes restarting consumer client it helped to solve the issue. I assume I didn't allocateted enough memory for messages or anything else ?